# Linking multiple buttons on a single page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to have three mobile pages in one page with three buttons link on it. It makes my mobile site look cleaner. This is the code I have:

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<?php include("head.php"); ?>


<!-- Start of Index -->
<div data-role="page" id="Index"  data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1><?php echo $businessname; ?> Contact Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
<a href="#yes" data-role="button">Yes</a>
<a href="#no" data-role="button">No</a>
<a href="#maybe" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
</div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of Yes -->
<div data-role="page" id="yes"  data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p><a href="#email">Back to foo</a></p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->



<!-- Start of No-->
<div data-role="page" id="no"  data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->



    <!-- Start of Maybe -->
<div data-role="page" id="maybe"  data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->





</div><!-- /page -->
```

Now only button one links to the page the rest doesn't. I have done extensive searching and from what I understand you need to link to your internal pages with `#yes #no #maybe`... what am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry i uploaded the wrong code, i have now uploaded the code i have the problems with

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you need the #yes #no, etc to be a tags on your page `<a name="no"></a>` you have it has `<div id="no">`

Also you have some unclosed `<div>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the page `divs` for "yes" and "no".

`href="#foo"` and `href="#email"` are not present. Did you want to go back to the Index page?
If so, just replace the `#foo` and `#email` with this

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back to foo</a>
```

I made these fixes and then your code works fine